# Getting Max, Mean and Min Temperatures of several sites ERA5

Tags: google-earth-engine, land-surface-temperature

I've been trying to export daily MAX, MIN and MEAN Temp for a specific region, but something seems to be wrong, because I can't get any value.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5/DAILY')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2021-08-01', '2022-01-01'));
                
var tempD = dataset.select('maximum_2m_air_temperature', 'mean_2m_air_temperature', 'minimum_2m_air_temperature');

var region = ee.FeatureCollection ('users/santiagomo/micro_CS')
Map.addLayer(region);
print (region) 

var list_tempD = tempD.toList(dataset.size());

var Temperature = tempD.map(function(image){
  var result = image
        .reduceRegions({ 
      collection:FTN,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
      scale: 5000,
        })
  var date = image.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd')
    return result.map(function(feat){ return feat.set('DATE', date)})

}).flatten();

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) { 
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}

print(Temperature)

// Export 
Export.table.toDrive({
 collection: Temperature,
 description: 'Temperatura',
 fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dataset request is out of range
Dataset Availability 1979-01-02T00:00:00Z–2020-07-09T00:00:00

Also it might give a solution

[Calculating daily max and min temperature data from GLDAS over several years using Google Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/395467/calculating-daily-max-and-min-temperature-data-from-gldas-over-several-years-usi)